# bulk insert with clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I created the following Query to bulk insert into my database.

```
Truncate table stg_connect_car

BULK INSERT   
   stg_connect_car 
          'correctPathToCSV\uc_export_connect_car.csv'
      WITH   (
        FIRSTROW = 2   
    ,   KEEPNULLS  
    ,   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'   
    ,   FIELDTERMINATOR = '|' 
);
```

When I try to run this sql statement I get the following error:

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common                           table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I tried adding a semicolon after the with clause (which seemed very remarkable to me) but it didn't work. The CSV file is Unicode, seperated with a pipe and ends with the line feed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Guessing `sql-server` (please don't tag products not involved), you need the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The from clause is missing after 'stg_connect_car'. Thanks HoneyBadger!